# Redis service crashes with "Failed opening the RDB file systemdd (in server root dir /etc/cron.d) for saving: Permission denied"

Tags: redis

I am running Redis server version 6.0.6 on Ubuntu 20.04. The process is run by "redis" user.

Sometimes, the Redis process crashes and gets restarted on its own and when this happens, lot of data cached in Redis becomes unavailable. This happens every few days/weeks. I can see the following messages in the logs - saving was working fine till 2:32:43 and suddenly failed at 2:34:15:

```
133121:C 23 Jun 2021 02:27:54.383 * RDB: 22 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:27:54.511 * Background saving terminated with success
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:29:46.279 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:29:46.354 * Background saving started by pid 133125
133125:C 23 Jun 2021 02:30:16.363 * DB saved on disk
133125:C 23 Jun 2021 02:30:16.464 * RDB: 18 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:30:16.583 * Background saving terminated with success
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:32:14.138 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:32:14.222 * Background saving started by pid 133131
133131:C 23 Jun 2021 02:32:42.924 * DB saved on disk
133131:C 23 Jun 2021 02:32:42.988 * RDB: 22 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:32:43.123 * Background saving terminated with success
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:14.958 * DB saved on disk
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:15.705 # Failed opening the RDB file systemdd (in server root dir /etc/cron.d) for saving: Permission denied


=== REDIS BUG REPORT START: Cut & paste starting from here ===
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:15.705 # Redis 6.0.6 crashed by signal: 11
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:15.705 # Crashed running the instruction at: 0x55f2e7e35099
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:15.705 # Accessing address: 0x149968
105798:M 23 Jun 2021 02:34:15.705 # Failed assertion: <no assertion failed> (<no file>:0)

------ STACK TRACE ------
EIP:
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(je_malloc_usable_size+0x89)[0x55f2e7e35099]

Backtrace:
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(logStackTrace+0x4f)[0x55f2e7db2bcf]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(sigsegvHandler+0xb5)[0x55f2e7db33d5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7fb934c173c0]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(je_malloc_usable_size+0x89)[0x55f2e7e35099]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(+0x50b79)[0x55f2e7d72b79]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(rdbSave+0x2ba)[0x55f2e7d9345a]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(saveCommand+0x67)[0x55f2e7d94ab7]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(call+0xb1)[0x55f2e7d6a8b1]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(processCommand+0x4a6)[0x55f2e7d6b446]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(processCommandAndResetClient+0x14)[0x55f2e7d799e4]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(processInputBuffer+0x18f)[0x55f2e7d7e39f]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(+0xe10ac)[0x55f2e7e030ac]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(aeProcessEvents+0x303)[0x55f2e7d63b83]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(aeMain+0x1d)[0x55f2e7d63ebd]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(main+0x4e5)[0x55f2e7d603d5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7fb934a370b3]
/usr/bin/redis-server 172.16.106.88:6379(_start+0x2e)[0x55f2e7d606ae]
```

The service restarts on its own and the Redis server starts working fine for a few days/weeks and crashes again with the same error!

I have checked several posts in SO, but none of them resolve my issue since:
a) The instance where the Redis server is running is in a private network (public access is disabled).
b) The DB file name and dir have not been corrupted as observed from "config get dbfilename" and "config get dir" commands. They show the default values.
c) The permissions of the directories are correct (/var/lib/redis is owned by redis with 755 permissions and /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb is owned by redis with 660 permissions)

Can anyone help me identify the root cause of this issue please?

Comment: The other answers you've seen are on the right track. This is an obvious sign of an attack. They're getting in *somehow*. Either your server *is* publicly accessible and you don't know it, or there is a compromised machine on your network. Luckily the attack doesn't seem to be succeeding against this redis, but you need to look into it (or get someone qualified to look into it) anyway.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out what caused this issue? I have been facing the exact same issue for a couple of weeks now, and this is the only resource I could find related to it

Comment: @DesTroy I disabled default user in Redis and allowed only connections using valid credentials to access Redis. I did not see this issue after this change! If you cannot do this change for some reasons, as a workaround, you can create an admin user having all permissions and remove the admin permissions from the default user - so whoever is trying to hack cannot do anything.

Comment: @ShobhanaSriram for us it happens on a server which is in a private network and has no outside access, but I'll still double check if there is any way to access it outside the private network.  Thanks for replying back.